# for loop behaving unexpectedly when used trying to remove passed list items

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, string-comparison

I am having a confusing time here. I have a list of items,which i pass it to a function. The function creates a duplicate list of the passed list, goes over each item, performs a string comparison and performs an action i.e remove. If i do not include the remove statement, the loop seems to be working alright but it behaves badly when i include it.
Below is my code

```
def myFunction(listItems):
    list1 = ['a','b','c','d']    
    duplicateList = []
    duplicateList = listItems
    
    for temp in listItems:
        if temp == 'tab1':
                print("debug 1")
                duplicateList.remove('tab1')                                
                #duplicateList.remove('tab1')                
                           
        elif temp == 'tab3':
                print("debug 2")

        elif temp == 'tab2':
            print("debug 3")
            for tempList in list1:
                print("debug 4")

    return listItems
        
print(myFunction(['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3']))
```

If `duplicateList.remove('tab1')` is commented out, the loop seems to work. However, even then the sequence of the loop is wrong. please guide me

Comment: ``duplicateList = listItems`` does not create a duplicate list.

Comment: You should not remove items from a list while you are iterating over it. This is what you are doing because `listItems` is a reference to the same list as `duplicateList`. If you made a copy of the list and iterated over the copy, it would work.

Comment: And you can make a copy using `duplicateList = listItems.copy()`  (There is also something called `deepcopy` but it is not needed here.)